# Как исправить проблему с панелью навигации в мобильном браузере?

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

В некоторых мобильных устройствах присутствует кнопки навигации, какие закрывают часть сайта. Есть сайт, где кнопки должны быть прижаты к низу, но эта панель закрывает их. Есть ли способ, чтобы эта панель не закрывала часть сайт?
[image: Рис. 1]

Comment: Была подобная проблема как раз таки на iOS устройствах и на сколько я знаю решить ее никак нельзя, такова особенность девайсов

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Единственно верный способ решения данной проблемы - на сайте должен быть нормальный скролл.